# .net producing broken jpegs in IE and FF

Tags: .net, image

This is driving me crazy, so...

When resizing image to small thumbnail, resulting image cannot be displayed in full by IE and FF. Opera shows the image correctly, and windows image preview also.

This is piece of code doing resizing:

```
     final_image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(92, 110)
     graphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(final_image)
     graphic.FillRectangle(New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White), New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 92, 110))
     graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
     graphic.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
     graphic.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
     graphic.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
     graphic.DrawImage(original_image, 0, 0, 92, 110)

     Dim info() As Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo = Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
     Dim encoderParameters As Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters
     encoderParameters = New Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1)
     encoderParameters.Param(0) = New Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L)
```

The result:

[This image should be missing it's lower 1/6 in FF3 and IE6/7 http://incito.hr/e387103c-b12f-4324-ac2d-a836e65a6bad-92x110.jpg](http://incito.hr/e387103c-b12f-4324-ac2d-a836e65a6bad-92x110.jpg)

In case your browser is showing the image above correctly (screen capture from FF3):

[Screen capture from FF3 http://incito.hr/Clipboard02.png](http://incito.hr/Clipboard02.png)

However, if I increase thumbnail size to 126x150 - everything is fine, in all browsers:

[Same image resized by the same code to 126x150 http://incito.hr/4d51a5cd-621e-4709-b24a-ebb8f9da54dd-126x150.jpg](http://incito.hr/4d51a5cd-621e-4709-b24a-ebb8f9da54dd-126x150.jpg)

Comment: So it's always trimming it into a square image?

Comment: Almost - the image displayed is 92x94px

Comment: My guess is the missing EOF is the fault of the camera or whatever took the picture.  I looked at the code I wrote in a graphics application and it's basically what you're doing so I don't think it's your fault.

Comment: Can't be the cameras fault because the input image is already processed by IrfanView (jpeg, cropped and resized)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be related to the EOI marker at the end of the image.

Something similar happened to me once and I vaguely remember that adding an EOI byte to the end of the JPG solved it.

I suggest you search the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) for EOI and try it.

Comment: Yes!!!! Thats it! I've opened the image in UltraEdit, added FF D9 at the end and it is displayed ok in FF and IE. Thanks a lot!

Comment: :) Glad it helped. No idea why this is, btw.. would be nice if someone explained it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you need to call `Flush` on the `Graphics` instance, i.e.:

```
graphic.Flush();
```

Do this when you've finished all the drawing operations, before you emit the stream from the bitmap.

Comment: Stream is saved to file and served as a file to browser. The problem is the same even in local mode. The image saving code is not displayed here

Comment: That's the same thing I've done in the past, and I've found that occasionally the bitmap file would be blank unless I made the call to Flush before saving the bitmap, so probably a good idea to add it if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on drawing context and may need calling Save or Flush method to solve as Earwicker said above.